# Dfferentiability a.e. and integrability

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to understand something. Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be absolutely continuous. Then, we know that $f$ is differentiable a.e. on $(a,b)$. We also know that its derivative $f'$ is "integrable", but what does that mean ? With the trace measure we can define the integral of a function on a subset of the whole space (it's the integral of the restriction), but here what do we need to do ? Do we need to consider the trace measure on the set on which $f'$ is defined, and then talk about integrability in this new space ?

Thank you in advance for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{x:f'(x)\, \text {exists}\}$ is measurable set. If you define $g$ to be $f'$ on this set and anything you like on the complement of this set then $g$ is measurable and its integrability does not depend on how you define $g$ outside $\{x:f'(x) \text {exists}\}$. So we can say $f'$ is integrable if any one of these $g$'s is integrable.

Comment: Typo in first line *"if you define $g$ to be $f$ on..."* should be *"if you define $g$ to be $f'$ on..."*

Comment: Thank you very much ! I understand it now

Answer (score 0):

We can only talk and make conclusions on $[a,b]$. Outside this interval we know nothing. So, all we need is that a function $F$ is AC if-f there is an integrable $f$ such that

$F(x)=F(a)$+$\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$. For a detailed account on this subject see [https://sites.ualberta.ca/~rjia/Math418/Notes/chap3.pdf](https://sites.ualberta.ca/%7Erjia/Math418/Notes/chap3.pdf)

or Royden's "Real Analysis".